# Subtract values from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to subtract total amount - paid amount which is **available.scheduleBudget - paidAmount.paid**

```
const available = [
  { scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: "11020" },
  { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: "11010" },
];

const paidAmount = [
  { paid: 88488, schudule_number: "11010" },
  { paid: 7140, schudule_number: "11020" },
];
```

Expected output :

```
[
  { balance: 1509512, schudule_number: "11010" },
  { balance: 14460, schudule_number: "11020" },
];
```

code to get output

```
Object.values(available).forEach((key) => {
  console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: Can either (or both) of `available` or `paidAmount` have items that share a schudule_number within their respective lists? i.e. Could two of the items in `available` have schudule_number 11020? Could two of the items in `paidAmount` have schudule_number 11020?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to generate a new object from `paidAmount` where `schudule_number` is the key and `paid` the value. Then you can simply [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `available` to subtract the appropriate `paid` amount from `scheduleBudget`:

```js
const available = [
  { scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: "11020" },
  { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: "11010" },
];

const paidAmount = [
  { paid: 88488, schudule_number: "11010" },
  { paid: 7140, schudule_number: "11020" },
];
 
const pA = {};
paidAmount.forEach(p => pA[p.schudule_number] = p.paid);

const result = available.map(({scheduleBudget, schudule_number}) => 
  ({ scheduleBudget: scheduleBudget-pA[schudule_number], schudule_number})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an object for the balances groupd by `schedule_number` and get the result from the object.

**This approach allows more than one payment for a `schedule_number`.**

```js
const
    available = [{ scheduleBudget: 21600, schedule_number: "11020" }, { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schedule_number: "11010" }],
    paidAmount = [{ paid: 88488, schedule_number: "11010" }, { paid: 7140, schedule_number: "11020" }],
    balances = Object.fromEntries(available.map(({ scheduleBudget, schedule_number }) =>
        [schedule_number, scheduleBudget]
    ));

paidAmount.forEach(({ paid, schedule_number }) => balanceses[schedule_number] -= paid);

const
    result = Object
    .entries(balances)
    .map(([schedule_number, balance]) => ({ balance, schedule_number }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you do this to get the answer:

```
const available = [
  { scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: '11020' },
  { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: '11010' },
]

const paidAmount = [
  { paid: 88488, schudule_number: '11010' },
  { paid: 7140, schudule_number: '11020' },
]

let finalAvailable = []
available.forEach((value) => {
  paidAmount.forEach((item) => {
    if (value.schudule_number === item.schudule_number) {
      scheduleBudget = value.scheduleBudget - item.paid
      finalAvailable.push({ scheduleBudget, schudule_number: item.schudule_number })
    }
  })
  return finalAvailable
})

console.log('finalAvailable:', finalAvailable)
```

```js
const available = [
  { scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: '11020' },
  { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: '11010' },
]

const paidAmount = [
  { paid: 88488, schudule_number: '11010' },
  { paid: 7140, schudule_number: '11020' },
]

let finalAvailable = []
available.forEach((value) => {
  paidAmount.forEach((item) => {
    if (value.schudule_number === item.schudule_number) {
      scheduleBudget = value.scheduleBudget - item.paid
      finalAvailable.push({ scheduleBudget, schudule_number: item.schudule_number })
    }
  })
  return finalAvailable
})

console.log('finalAvailable:', finalAvailable)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want use `forEach` you need to create a third object and `forEach` both object and substract the value when ticket fit together

```js
const available = [{scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: '11020'},
    {scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: '11010'}];

const paidAmount = [{paid: 88488, schudule_number: '11010'},
    {paid: 7140, schudule_number: '11020'}];
let newOutput = [];
Object.values(available).forEach(keyavailable => {
    Object.values(paidAmount).forEach(keypaidAmount => {
        if (keyavailable.schudule_number === keypaidAmount.schudule_number) {
            let sub = keyavailable.scheduleBudget - keypaidAmount.paid;
            let data = {'balance': sub, 'schudule_number': keypaidAmount.schudule_number};
            newOutput.push(data);
        }
    })
})
console.log(newOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order in `available` and `paidAmount` arrays not must match the `schulude_number`:

```js
const available =  [ { scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: '11020' },    { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: '11010' } ];
const paidAmount =  [ { paid: 88488, schudule_number: '11010' },    { paid: 7140, schudule_number: '11020' } ];


function pay(budgets, paid) {
  const budgetObj = budgets.reduce((a,b) => {
    a[b.schudule_number] = {balance:b.scheduleBudget, schudule_number:b.schudule_number};
    return a;
  },{});
  paid.forEach(p => budgetObj[p.schudule_number].balance -= p.paid);
  return Object.values(budgetObj);
}
console.log(pay(available, paidAmount));
```

Answer (score 0):

If both of `available` and `paidAmount` have items that share a schudule_number within their respective lists then perhaps something like this would work:

```js
const available = [{ scheduleBudget: 21600, schudule_number: "11020" }, { scheduleBudget: 1598000, schudule_number: "11010" }];
const paidAmount = [{ paid: 88488, schudule_number: "11010" }, { paid: 7140, schudule_number: "11020" }];

const balances = [...available, ...paidAmount].reduce(
  (acc, item) => Object.assign(
    acc,
    {
      [item.schudule_number]: (acc[item.schudule_number] || 0) +
        (item.scheduleBudget || 0) - (item.paid || 0)
    }
  ),
  {}
);

const result = Object.entries(balances).map(
  ([schudule_number, balance]) => ({ schudule_number, balance })
);

console.log(result);
```